# Customization of Project Service Automation (PSA) for Microsoft Dynamics 365

Tags: javascript, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I needed to add a custom column in the Work Breakdown Structure (WBS) that PSA implements for each project entity. It shows the project tasks with some default columns, with a Microsoft Project appearence (and functionality).

[image: This is an example of the WBS of PSA for Dynamics]

The problem with this tool is that you cannot open any task from it. So, I wanted to insert a column which allow the user to do that. How to difficult is it?

Answer (score 3):

Well, the only way I found to get that is by changing the PSA's JS libraries. 
This is very dangerous, because any update performed in the future could make your solution crash.
However, since I could not find documentation nor workarounds explaining how to perform what I needed, I decided to bring to you both, the problem and the solution I came across with at the same time.

1.-  Create a solution with the PSA’s JS libraries we have to change using the Add Existing button. These are the **components**:

- msdyn_/Common/Models/ProjectTask.js
- msdyn_/Project/WBS/Scripts/ViewModelTaskFactory.js
- msdyn_/Project/WBS/Scripts/WBSView.js
- msdyn_/Project/WBS/View/ViewTaskInitializer.js

2.- Since these are critical files for the PSA performance, export it as **unmanaged solution**. In order to have some kind of back up file, just in case.

3.- Modifications on the resource **msdyn_/Common/Models/ProjectTask.js**:

Here is where data between the entity and our view model is mapped. If the field you want to show is a custom field of the ProjectTask Entity, you have to assign its value to the JS variable which is create in the function
ProjectTask(entity) and the prototype "initFromFetchXmlResponse", like this:

```
this.myVariableField=entity.fieldAttribute; //this in projectTask(entity)
this.myVariableField=fetchXmlEntity.fieldAttribute; //this initFromFetchXmlResponse
```

I just wanted to create a link to the task, therefore this was no necessary for me.

4.- Changes on the resource **msdyn_/Project/WBS/Scripts/ViewModelTaskFactory.js**:

This file contains the functions which create the viewModelTask, which is some kind of row fill with the task values. For each column we would like to add to the WBS, we will have to insert some lines in the "createDefaultViewModelTask" and "createViewModelTaskFromProjectTask" functions.

```
viewModelTask.myDefaultValueInColumn="";//createDefaultViewModelTask
viewModelTask.myActualValueInColumn=projectTask.Attribute;//createViewModelTaskFromProjectTask
```

5.- Changes on the resource **msdyn_/Project/WBS/View/ViewTaskInitializer.js**:
Here is where columns itself are defined. We have to add some code to the ViewTaskInitializer function and the "defineTask" fields declaration:

```
ViewTaskInitializer.taskNameColumn = 'taskAttributeName';//ViewTaskInitializer
{ name: ViewTaskInitializer.taskNameColumn, type: 'string' }//defineTask
```

6.- Changes on the resource **msdyn_/Project/WBS/Scripts/WBSView.js**:
On this JS are located the files which perform the actual "row-painting" features. We need to change the function "gridConfiguration", and add our column to the "this.Ext.create" method.
For the gridConfiguration we will add this array within the series:

```
            {
              id: ViewTaskInitializer_1.default.OurColumnName,
              label: ''
            }
```

Regarding the column addition on the second function, it could be like this:

```
             {
                header: 'OurColumnHeader',
                align: 'center',
                dataIndex: ViewTaskInitializer_1.default.OurColumnName,
                width: 800,
                sortable: true,
                resizable: true,
                readOnly: false,
                renderer: function (value, record) {
                    //here is the code which returns the value
                   // you can access the current task is trying to paint like this:
                   var task=record.record.data;
                          }

            }
```